# search for key navigation property is O(1)?

Tags: c#, hashset, poco

I have entity POCO to use with entity freamwork. This entities are created by EF, and I see that the properties that are collections are ICollection and the object that is created is a hashset.

So if I want to search for an entity I can do this:

```
MyPoco.MyProperty.FirstOrDefault(x => x == MyPocoToSearch);
```

This is a O(1) complex because it is compare objects of the hashset.

However, many times the objects can be different, because one objects is from the client layer and the other object is from dbContext, so if I use the object to compare, I would get false because they are different objects. So I would need to search by ID, something like that:

```
MyPoco.MyProperty.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == MyClientPoco.ID);
```

But in this case I am searching with a property, so I guess it isn't O(1). Would I need to implement the ICompare interface?

Thanks.

Comment: Those have the same complexity, `O(n)`.  You're searching each element in the list until you find the desired element.

Comment: Why don't you just use _[context.MyStuff.Find (MyClientPoco.ID)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx)_